# Does notification in Android SDK 26 and above supports SDK below 26?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-notifications

So I have the following code for notification in Android SDK 26 and above:
First, I have a wrapper class that wraps over the whole application and I declare notification channel in this class:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O ) {
        NotificationChannel Channel = new NotificationChannel(
                "channel",
                "myChannel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        );


        Channel.setDescription("My Event Channel");

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(Channel);

    }
```

and notification service is being called upon tapping a button :

```
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"channel")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText("my notification")
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                .build();

        notificationManager.notify(0,notification);
```

So my question is that for SDK below 26, the channel is not getting created. So will the code above also work for SDK below 26?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use an emulator/physical and test it, then if it doesn't work, make a proper question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I don't have any device with SDK below 26 ...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer:

Yes it works but with minor changes.

### Long Answer:

So I found the detailed way to test on devices with SDK below 26:

1. You can configure API level in setting up an emulator as the following figure:

[image]

In the image above, I have selected Pixel emulator and can select the desired API level to be installed (*My API level is 22*)

2. Then proceed to installing the API and configuring the emulator
3. Once you have your emulator up & running, pay attention to the code below:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel Channel = new NotificationChannel(
                "channel",
                "myChannel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        );
   AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .build();
   Uri sound = Uri.parse(
                    ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
                    "://" +
                    getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +
                    "/" +
                    R.raw.void_event
            );


   Channel.setDescription("My Event Channel");
   Channel.setSound(sound, audioAttributes)

        NotificationManager manager =    getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(Channel);

    }
```

The code above sets channel priority(**NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH**) and sound (**setSound(sound, audioAttributes)**) working only if your API is above 26.

4. What you can do is that you can also add these lines of code when notification is going to be triggered such as tapping a button or receiving push notification (where you are working with **NotificationCompat.Builder**):

```
// Define sound 
Uri sound = Uri.parse(
                    ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
                            "://" +
                            context.getPackageName() +
                            "/" +
                            R.raw.void_event
            );

`enter code here`NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =          NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"channel")
// The next 2 lines of code is for adding sound & priority for API < 26
// For devices with API > 26, it just ignores it
                .setSound(sound, AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText("my notification")
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                .build();

        notificationManager.notify(0,notification);
```